# collection_select in given example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

application_controller.rb

```
  def find_user_favorites
    @user_fav_categories = current_user.favorites.map(&:category)
  end
```

this is how I currently list all category names:

```
    <% @user_fav_categories.each do |fav| %>
      <%= fav.name %>
    <% end %>
```

how can i make a list using collection_select?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is what collection you'll use, try this one

```
collection_select(
  Category,
  :name,
  Category.joins(:favorites).where('favorites.user_id: current_user.id),
  :id,
  :name
)
```

Comment: how doesn't it work? but anyways you get the idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<%=collection_select(Category, :name, @user_fav_categories, :id, :name)%>
```